# System.nanotime return wildly different times

Tags: java, lwjgl

So i'm trying to implement a sort of day-night cycle in my game, and I'm using System.nanotime() to get the approximate time passed between frames, the problem is that it sometimes jumps huge amounts of time

Using lwjgl, and calling Timer.update() before swapBuffers with vsync enabled should be around 16.6ms increase to the current time each loop shouldnt it? Yet it can be much much higher than that with no actual slowdown for rendering

Here's the code : Time class

```
public class Time
{
    public static final long SECOND = 1000000000L;

    private static long lastTime;

    public static long getTime()
    {
        return System.nanoTime();
    }

    public static double getDelta()
    {
        return (double)(getTime() - lastTime) / SECOND;
    }

    public static void update()
    {
        Time.lastTime = Time.getTime();
    }
}
```

Update method

```
    while ( !glfwWindowShouldClose(window) )
    {
        input();
        update();
        render();
    }

public void update()
{
    //System.out.println("Time since last update " + Time.getDelta());
    Time.update();
}
```

And where i'm using the delta time :

```
    if ((timeOfDay + Time.getDelta()) < timeDayTotal)
        timeOfDay += Time.getDelta();
    else
        timeOfDay += Time.getDelta() - timeDayTotal;
    System.out.println("Time of day " + timeOfDay);
```

Ignoring the fact that the precision seems to be waaaay off for now, here's some sample output

```
Time of day 0.0077873133
Time of day 0.0077988105
Time of day 0.0078120963
Time of day 0.007860638
Time of day 0.015185255
Time of day 0.01879608
Time of day 0.01880809
Time of day 0.018820863
Time of day 0.018835938
Time of day 0.018851267
```

It seems to mostly increment the correct amount (by a factor of 10^-4, but close enough, thats not the problem), but then it has these massive jumps up that I can't explain

So finally, a) whats the problem with system.nanoTime and b) is there a fix or viable replacement?

Edit : Switched to currentTimeMillis(), the precision is gone which is no big deal, but the jumps are still there

```
Time of day 0.03
Time of day 0.03
Time of day 0.03
Time of day 0.03
Time of day 0.06
Time of day 0.06
Time of day 0.06
Time of day 0.06
```

Comment: You call `Time.getDelta()` way too many times.  Call it once when you enter the time measuring code and save the value to use in the conditions.  When you say there are jumps are you referring to the .073 s jump between the 4th and 5th entries in the first list? What code was running between calls to the code that printed the delta?  what does `inpu()` do? How can you expect any help with most of the critical code not visible?

Comment: Input does nothing critical to this, the jumps were the large steps that you mentioned, I've changed the getDelta to return the time between frames, and now timeOfDay produces a static number, I'll update my posted code

Comment: What is `timeDayTotal` and why do you subtract it in  one case?  Please don't make us drag the full problem out of you one question at a time.

Comment: And now the code is materially different... Moving targets are HIGHLY frowned upon here.

Comment: timeDayTotal was the value I was using to specify the total day length, at this point it's completely redundant because i've removed the checks against it
I'm sorry i'm changing my code as I get suggestions, should I change it back and just update my code locally as I get suggestions?

Comment: No, change the code to reflect the question you want answered. But if the semantics / meaning of the question changes significantly and invalidates existing answers you should ask a new question, being more careful to ensure that it's a solid question that isn't going to change.

Comment: Ahh, i see, Well the question is kinda still the same
Something is producing huge steps up in elapsed time, with no other indication that it's happened other than in the timeOfDay part, and I dont understand why

Comment: My money is on Garbage Collection or something happening in a different thread. If you run the problematic section a few million times is the jump always at the same point, and of the same magnitude?

Comment: Always about 2 seconds in, then later its inconsistent, but the weird part is that after about 30 seconds it seems to stop happening
Garbage collection seems likely, now I looked up what it is
Also, the jumps arent consistent in size

Comment: Could also be the JVM doing JIT compilation.. once it's done, things stabilize, and afaik it only kicks in for methods which are run many times, which might explain the initial period of stability..

Comment: I just let it run for a full minute (well, judging by it which is bad)
It jumped from 0.7s to 16s to 19s, then it did no more jumping
Would that be JIT compilation?

Answer (score 0):

> In general, do not use System.nanoTime() in any program which you don’t plan to strongly control how it is run, and the environment it is run in.
>   ..
>
> The problem lies in the RDTSC instruction which retrieves the number of CPU ticks since the CPU started. On multi-core systems, each core will have its own tick count, and they will not match, so every time your process switches CPUs, you get a different measurement. The issue is compounded by the fact that some power management systems actually alter the CPU’s frequency to save power, which breaks the functionality even on single core, single CPU systems.

From [here](http://www.principiaprogramatica.com/?p=16)

Comment: Do you have an alternative I can use seeing as nanotime is next to useless for me?

Comment: I would probably 'try' to check the new java.time api from java 8, something like:

`Instant before = Instant.now();
Instant after = Instant.now();
long delta = Duration.between(before, after).toNanos();`

But I wouldn't think that might help, since the problem is inherently elsewhere (hardware dependent).

Comment: Going to look at this Instant api, maybe this will fix it

Answer (score 0):

From the code you posted, it looks like you update() the Time on each frame before rendering, so then when you use getDelta() you only measure the time it took to get there, rather than the whole frame time?

I think it should look more like this:

```
public class Time
{
    public static final long SECOND = 1000000000L;
    public static final double timeDayTotal = 100.0; // ?

    private static final long start = System.nanoTime();
    private static double timeOfDay;

    public static void update() {
        long now = System.nanoTime();
        timeOfDay = (now - start) / (double)SECOND % timeDayTotal;
    }

    public static double getTimeOfDay()
    {
        return timeOfDay;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've removed the if statement for now, just want time to increment at a fairly consistent rate
Doing that, time of day still returns massive jumps

Comment: it's not the if statement that's the problem.. if you have update() in one place and getDelta() in another place, you're only measuring the time between them (and then ignoring the time between getDelta() and next update()).. And I think what you want is to measure time between one frame's getDelta() and another frame's getDelta(), so to speak, so you have to put it all in one place..

Comment: I just removed the if statement for concise-ness, I know that wasnt the problem
I'll bear that in mind while trying to come up with a way to do this neatly

Comment: I tried that code out, timeOfDay is now putting out an unchanging value
I removed my old update method and switched solely to the code you posted (because updating time twice seems redundant)